# Redirect incoming traffic from OpenVPN server to OpenVPN client

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, iptables, openvpn

I have OpenVPN Server (PiVPN + PiHole) (LAN IP: 192.168.0.200 VPN IP: 192.168.10.1) and I have also OpenVPN client (VPN IP: 192.168.10.2). And I want to if I enter to my browser http://192.168.0.200:84 it's show me the website from http://192.168.10.2:80.

```
pi@JNDServer:~ $ cat VPN.txt
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.2 on Sat Sep  5 01:06:31 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2139:316887]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [895:339256]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1738:473525]
-A INPUT -d 192.168.10.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 192.168.10.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1280 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep  5 01:06:31 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.2 on Sat Sep  5 01:06:31 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [252:17107]
:INPUT ACCEPT [223:15327]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [189:14460]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [36:3185]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 32400 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:32400                                                                                                                                              
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1280 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.2:80                                                                                                                                                          
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -o eth0 -m comment --comment openvpn-nat-rule                                                                                                                                                              -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep  5 01:06:31 2020
```